# Confluence Plug-In where to define HTML code

Tags: javascript, confluence

I am new in the development of Confluence Add-Ons. I want to use the example from the API. For instance look at this Page [Dialog 2](https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/dialog2.html), there are the HTML-Code and the JS-Code separated.

I know how to define a JS-File and how to refer to the `atlassian-plugin.xml`.

Look here

```
<web-resource key="Confluence-resources" name="Confluence-Web-Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="confluence.js" location="/js/confluence.js"/>

  </web-resource>
```

But where I must define the HTML-Code?

Answer (score 2):

In essence, you need to render the HTML from `execute` method in your `Macro` class. But, practically speaking, there're a few "Atlassian-approved" approaches.

You might want to consider built-in Velocity templating support from `VelocityUtils.getRenderedTemplate` method.

Quoting [Atlassian's Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-architecture/confluence-internals/velocity-template-overview/rendering-velocity-templates-in-a-macro), you can probably write something like:

```
public String execute(Map params, String body, RenderContext renderContext) throws MacroException {
    // do something with params ...

    Map context = MacroUtils.defaultVelocityContext();
    context.put("page", page);
    context.put("labels", labels);
    return VelocityUtils.getRenderedTemplate("com/atlassian/confluence/example/sample-velocity.vm", context);
}
```

In recent years, they started to promote the usage `Soy Template` too.